# Drawing "stuck" when scrolling vertically but not horizontally

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a java application which allows the user to place images within a jScrollPane. The application displays a box which snaps to a grid to show where the tile will be placed as well as some information about options and the position in the overall pane. I am running the program on a Mac running Lion. When using the trackpad to scroll horizontally the information painted around the cursor is updated and moves with the cursor. However, while scrolling vertically the information and box that indicates where the tile will be placed drag rather than being updated with the cursor's position stay where they where and are left behind without updating until the mouse is moved. Also the information and box do not get repainted while using the arrow keys to scroll either vertically or horizontally.

I am assuming that the problem is that it is not calling the paint method, however I do not know how to call the paint method while scrolling or why it still seems to call it when only scrolling horizontally with the trackpad. Below is the code where the jScrollPane is initialized and the paint method.

ScrollPane:

```
public class Map extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8527533451039189417L;
    final int AREA_SIZE_X = 100;
    final int AREA_SIZE_Y = 100;
    JFrame sWindow;
    mapPanel mPanel;
    JScrollPane mScrollPane;

    Map() throws IOException
        {
            mPanel = new mapPanel(sWindow);
            this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            mScrollPane = new JScrollPane(mPanel);
            this.getContentPane().add(mScrollPane);
            mPanel.requestFocus(); 
            this.setTitle("Map maker");
            this.setLocation(400, 0);
            this.setResizable(false);

            this.pack();
        }
}
```

Paint Method:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, AREA_SIZE_X * 20, AREA_SIZE_Y * 20);
            mouseLocation = this.getMousePosition();

            if (this.hasFocus() && this.contains(mouseLocation))
                {
                    g.drawImage(bFS.get(sWindow.getSelected()), mouseLocation.x - 20, mouseLocation.y - 20, this);
                    g.setColor(Color.red);
                    g.drawRect(((mouseLocation.x - 10) / 20) * 20, ((mouseLocation.y - 10) / 20) * 20, 20, 20);
                    String xDisp = "x: " + ((mouseLocation.x - 10) / 20);
                    String yDisp = "y: " + ((mouseLocation.y - 10) / 20);
                    g.drawString(xDisp, mouseLocation.x - 20, mouseLocation.y + 25);
                    g.drawString(yDisp, mouseLocation.x - 20, mouseLocation.y + 40);
                    String layerDisp = "Layer: " + sWindow.isLayered();
                    g.drawString(layerDisp, mouseLocation.x - 20, mouseLocation.y + 55);
                    int tempCounter = 0;
                    while (tempCounter < 4 && tiles[((mouseLocation.x - 10) / 20)][((mouseLocation.y - 10) / 20)][tempCounter] != -1)
                        {
                            tempCounter++;
                        }
                    String layerLevelDisp = "Num Layers: " + tempCounter;
                    g.drawString(layerLevelDisp, mouseLocation.x - 20, mouseLocation.y + 70);

                }
        }
```

Comment: Please note that .getMousePosition() always returns the position relative to the component or null, if the mouse is outside the component - and not the absolute mouse position.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).